# 'method' parameter doesn't exist in qplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The documentation for qplot doesn't contain the 'method' parameter.
The error I get is -

```
> qplot(displ, hwy, data = mpg, geom=c("point", "smooth"),facets=.~drv,method="loess")
Error: Unknown parameters: method
```

My version of R is 3.2.1 and ggplot2 version is 2.0.0, if it helps.

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  It's best to follow these so we can help you with your problem

Comment: I don't think you need to call the method.  Try it without

Comment: @Amstell I apologize. This was my first question here and I tried to follow the rules the best I could.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need for `method` as `geom_smooth()` assumes `loess`

```
qplot(displ, hwy, data = mpg, geom=c("point", "smooth"),facets=.~drv)
```

> If geom="smooth", a loess fit line and confidence limits are added by
>   default. When the number of observations is greater than 1,000, a more
>   efficient smoothing algorithm is employed. Methods include "lm" for
>   regression, "gam" for generalized additive models, and "rlm" for
>   robust regression. The formula parameter gives the form of the fit.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This works. However, neither 'method' nor 'formula' are available as parameters, for some reason. I can't add a simple regression line because it won't accept `method="lm"`. Is there any way out for this?

Comment: @MihirSawant You're using `qplot`. `method` is a parameter to `stat_smooth`... either `qplot(...) + stat_smooth()` or switch to the `ggplot()` syntax. `qplot` is for quick plots (hence the name); it's not meant to be used for large degrees of customization.

Comment: @Alex I'm aware that I can use the `ggplot()` syntax, however I was working on one of the [swirl](http://swirlstats.com/) exercises and progressing through it required me to type in the exact command that I've mentioned in the example of the original post. But for some reason R studio and even the base R console wouldn't accept both the parameters. Hence, the question.

Answer (score 8):

Welcome to SO. 
You're getting the error because of the update in `ggplot2`; the tutorial that you're looking at was probably from an older version. You will see that at a lot of places on the internet.

For reference: On this forum, one generally posts the objective of the exercise, the exact (or minimum working example) code and output and *states* the efforts made at the stage where stuck. This helps the other members give a more coherent answer.